# Webpack build error

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Having some issues with webpack. It builds fine but when I open my site, i get: `Getting error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined"`

I believe my CommonsChunkPlugin is running before my app is bundled?

It may help to know I have my config in `src/config/webpack.config.js` which is building to `dist/js/`.

Have read https://medium.com/@MarkEwersDev/note-to-self-if-you-ever-get-this-uncaught-referenceerror-webpackjsonp-is-not-defined-message-and-d354f5c4d335#.9cysuil5p and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/368 but neither seem to help unless I am missing something.

```
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: {
    vendor: [
      'react', 'react-dom', 'react-router', 'react-helmet', 'react-redux', 'moment-timezone', 'cookies-js', 'superagent', 'classnames', 'es6-promise'
    ],
    app: [
      './src/client/entry',
      './scss/main.scss',

    ]
  }
  output:{
    path: __dirname + '../../dist/js',
    filename: 'app.js'
  }
  plugins:[
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.js'),

    new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/app.css', {
        allChunks: true
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env':{
        'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: true
      },
      output: {
        comments: false
      }
    }),
    ...persistentPlugins
  ],
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `webpackJsonp` function is defined by the commons chunk, so you must always put the commons chunk (`vendor.js` in your case) first when writing `<script>` tags. You also can't use `<script async>`.

Another possibility is that your vendor chunk is being overwritten by the entry chunk as you set `output.filename` to a constant string. Try naming it `[name].js` instead of `app.js`.

Comment: Looks like I was loading my scripts in the wrong order. That has fixed my webpackJsonp error. 

Only my header is loading now but I am not getting any errors in my console or my server logs which is not helpful at all.

Comment: Need to load polyfills.js, then vendor.js, then app.js

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem on my production environment. I don't know why, but when I upload just the bundle + vendors, built with the production webpack config, I get the same error. I just solved this error restarting the node application. But I know that it's not a good approach.

I'm using exactly the same plugins on my webpack production config as you, and I'm quite sure that the reason is one of the webpack optimization plugins.

**My suggestion is:**
Try to comment one by one of those optimization plugins (*AggressiveMergingPlugin*, *DedupePlugin* and *UglifyJsPlugin*), and you might find out which one is causing the problem.

I can't test it right now because it just happens on my production environment and I can't stop/test it at this time. But, if it works for you, please let me know :)

Comment: I was able to resolve my issue with the marked answer above